# Broadcom BCM5716 Hangs on CentOS 6 Boot

Tags: boot, linux-networking, nic, centos6, broadcom

I have a fresh CentOS 6 installation on a Dell R310 server with a Broadcom BCM5716. The onboard NIC is causing the boot to hang for some reason.

```
Welcome to CentOS Linux
Starting udev: udev: starting version 147
Boardcom NetXtreme II Gigabit Ethernet Driver bnx2 v2.0.23b (Feb 01, 2011)
bnx2 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
```

That's it... then it just hangs / freezes.  If I disable the NIC via the BIOS settings, CentOS boots fine.

I've downloaded and installed the latest driver from [Broadcom's website](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/netxtremeii.php). Any ideas?

Comment: we have a very similar centos 6 issue with a broadcom 5754. I wonder if this will be the same issue ? - Keeping an eye on this one

Comment: Just a little update -- I've spent so much frustrated time trying to get this working on various linux distros that I just went out and bought a new Intel Pro Server NIC. Worked like a charm with CentOS 5 and 6 -- no hassles. Definitely worth the $150.

Comment: ditto :( same outcome here

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old now, but I came across it and thought I'd mention that we also had issues with this NIC on-board a Dell R710.  Here's a link with some things you might try:

http://answerpot.com/showthread.php?290594-Dell%20Power%20Edge%20R710%20with%20CentOS

A colleague ended up resolving it with a combination of these steps.

**Summary:**

- Update the card's firmware
- Get the latest Broadcom driver
- Disable MSI; i.e. add 'options bnx2 disable_msi=1' to /etc/modprobe.conf and
  reboot.

Comment: +1 Firmware, it's always the firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move it to another slot.
If it does not help file an RMA with your vendor.

update: Then try to reset the BIOS settings. If it does not help contact your vendor

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Another slot as in PCI slot or something?  If so, unfortunately this is the onboard (embedded) NIC on the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I see this behavior alot with HP and ICO servers (ICO = local HW vendor). We usually solve it by either disabling all but one interface in BIOS or connecting all LAN ports with a switch so they have a link.